# Updating events in FileMaker FullCalendar implementation without reloading

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, filemaker

I am trying to implement a FullCalendar solution in my FileMaker database. I'm using FullCalendar V6. I am able to display the calendar and events successfully, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to update events in the calendar without reloading the webviewer completely.

I am using the following javascript code to initialize the calendar:

```
var EVENTS = ***{{EVENTS}}***;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        initialDate: '2023-05-02',
        height: '100%',
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        navLinks: true,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        timeZone: 'local',
        selectable: true,
        nowIndicator: true,
        events: EVENTS,
        dateClick: onDateClick,
        eventClick: onEventClick,
        eventChange: onEventChange, 
    });

    calendar.render();
```

Then in my FileMaker `loadCalendar` script, I am able to use text substitution to substitute in an array of event objects for `***{{EVENTS}}***` and the calendar will load with all the events in place.

The issue with this approach is that in order to update the events in the calendar, I have to call `loadCalendar` and completely reload the webviewer in order to refresh it. I am trying to figure out a way to avoid using text substitution and instead use the `Perform Javascript in Webviewer` FileMaker script step to update the events without reloading the entire webviewer, but I am at a loss. Could anyone help point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: You have a couple of options to implement a dynamic event feed in fullCalendar - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function.